# What is the target charset when I encrypt a string with Cipher and Base64.Encoder?

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding, base64

I'm trying to accommodate encrypted tokens in a DSL I'm designing (i.e. I need a char to be used as delimiter).  The `encoder.encodeToString(...)` docs says it uses the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) charset.  But when I encrypt a sampling of texts, it looks like it's not using all of the ISO-8859-1 charset, instead upper/lower-case and some symbols, and not certain punctuation and accented chars.  What am I missing about this `encodeToString()` call and what is the final char domain?

```
//import java.util.Base64;
//import javax.crypto.Cipher;
//import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
static Cipher cipher;
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
    String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Comment: But Base64 only uses letters, digits and a couple of special characters to encode binary data.

Comment: This method will use whatever the default character set has been set to on the JVM that runs it.

Comment: The documentation is telling, as the Base64 encoding delivers one 64 ASCII characters, it uses ISO-8859-1 for String-to-byte conversion of Base64 String values. As ISO-8859-1 is permissive, all input data errors will be passed to the Base64 decoding. ASCII (7 bits!) or UTF-8 (specific multibyte sequences) do not guarantee that property.

Answer (score 3):

String has a constructor with charset; otherwise the default OS charset is taken.

```
new String(decryptedByte, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

As there often is a mix-up of Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) with Windows Latin-1 (Windows-1252) you might try "Windows-1252" too.

Answer (score 1):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is named just so because it uses 64 characters from the ASCII table. The encoding used should not matter as long as it is compatible with ASCII.

If you want to use more than 64 characters you will have to use a different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption returns bytes, no matter the encryption is.

I personally use the following function to convert from decrypted bytes to string:

```
    public static String getStringFromBytes(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        for (byte b : data) {
            sb.append((char) (b));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Well, you are doing the wrong thing. There is a difference between `byte` and `char` and some characters - especially in languages other than English - cannot be represented by bytes. Furthermore, an encoded value in bytes covers the whole range of 0-255, while some of this range doesn't map to actual characters.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [document line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) carefully:

> This method first **encodes all input bytes into a base64 encoded byte
>   array** and then **constructs a new String by using the encoded byte array
>   and the ISO-8859-1 charset**.

This means 2 things:

- Encoding scheme used is `Base64`, that's the reason you can not getting expected output because `ISO-8859-1` is not used as encoding scheme.
- ISO-8859-1 is only used as charset reference for constructing String.

[Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class give your encoders and decoders for the Base64 encoding scheme, so if you are using its encoders and decoders then output will be encoded/decoded using `Base64` encoding scheme.

> This class consists exclusively of static methods for obtaining
>   **encoders and decoders for the Base64 encoding scheme**.

So, what you need is to properly encode your byte array using some encoding scheme - `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1`.

I would personally recommend using "UTF-8" because it is widely used + it encodes all ASCII and some Latin character in 1 byte, Unicode other BMP character using 2 byte and Unicode supplementary characters using 4 bytes. So, it is not space consuming for all ASCII and some Latin character + ability to encode all Unicode characters.

There are many ways you can find to encode your String using desired encoding scheme, an example below:

```
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[3];
    String decodeText = new String(byteArr);
    Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(decodeText);
```

Comment: Does it answer you question? When you use encoders and decoders from Base64 class then you get Base64 encoding scheme (for encoding you string) and ISO-8859-1 as reference charset.